# Can we incorporate Adobe Bracket into PySide TextEditor?

Tags: python-2.7, text-editor, pyside, adobe-brackets

I want to incorporate Adobe Bracket in my python-pyside program. Can it be done? If not, are there any other open source text editor that can be incorporate into my pyside program.

Please, also tell me how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Bracket is a html/css/js editor hosted in a [CEF browser](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/). You can embed CEF browser in Python using [CEF Python](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/), so theoretically it should be possible. Here is an example of [embedding CEF browser in PySide app](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/source/browse/cefpython/cef3/windows/binaries/pyside.py).

Adobe Bracket's javascript code is communicating with C++ via javascript bindings (to save a file to a hard drive for example), so it would be required to reimplement some set of features in Python.